# Populating dropdown menu with server values - knockout.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, knockout.js

I have a basic form that allow a user to add as many courses as possible. Each course has to belong to a curriculum. I decided to build this on top of the knockout.js framework. I have been able to hard code the values for the curriculum drop down menu(`self.curriculumList`). But I am having difficulties fetching the values from mysql db to populate the dropdown menu. How can I do that? [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/adNuR/3353/)

```
var initialData = [{
       courseName: ""

   }];/**/

   var CourseModel = function (courses) {
       var self = this;
       self.courses = ko.observableArray(ko.utils.arrayMap(courses, function (course) {
           return {
               courseName: course.courseName,
               selectedOptionValue : course.selectedOptionValue
           };
       }));


       self.curriculumList = $.getJSON('functions/getCurriculum.php', function(data) {
        data;
       });

       self.addCourse = function () {
           self.courses.push({
               courseName: "",
               selectedOptionValue : ko.observable("Select One")
           });
       };

       self.removeCourse = function (course) {
           self.courses.remove(course);
       };

       self.save = function() {
        self.lastSavedJson(JSON.stringify(ko.toJS(self.courses), null, 2));
       };


      self.lastSavedJson = ko.observable("");
   };

   ko.applyBindings(new CourseModel(initialData));
```

Comment: where is your ajax call?

Comment: @raheelshan I added it, `self.curriculumList = $.getJSON..` but now i get [object Object] show in the dropdown list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The ajax call is asynchonous, so you need to access the data in the success callback and assign it to the observable array...

```
   self.curriculumList = ko.observableArray();
   $.getJSON('functions/getCurriculum.php', function(data) {
       self.curriculumList(data);
   });
```